# If we import one package in java program means Is there need to extend it?

Tags: java

If we import one package in java program means Is there need to extend it?

```
import Apack.Bpack.Myclass

class Thisclass extends Myclass{
}
```

my question is whether we need extends here?

for example
if i want a variable from Myclass then need to extend or import or both?

Comment: vinoth, please accept answers on your questions.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You only need the extends declaration if you want to subclass the Myclass class.

If on the other hand you simply want to reference the Myclass type and utilise it within Thisclass then you can get away with simply importing it.  For example you may wish to declare a method in Thisclass that takes a single parameter of type Myclass...

```
public void doSomething(Myclass theClass) { // do something }
```

Doing so requires you to import the Myclass type - which in turn helps the compiler to identify the Myclass class during compilation.

Comment: if i want a variable from Myclass then need to extend or import or both?

Comment: If you to use a variable of type Myclass in Thisclass then you only need to import

Answer (score 2):

No. `extends` is used only if you want to subclass another class.

So, using

```
import Apack.Bpack.Myclass
class Thisclass { }
```

is perfectly fine.

Think about it. Since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance (subclassing multiple classes), what would you do if you had more than one import in your class?

Importing a class is used to tell to Java compiler: I want to use that class somewhere in my class and how I use it is up to me.

Extending that class is an option, and not mandatory.